# Issue with accessing the state and method in jest

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme, higher-order-components

I've been working around with unit tests using jest in React and HOC. Currently, I am facing an issue in accessing the state and method of my class. Check the sample code below

//Login.Container.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
          isShowLoader: false,
       };
       this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit() {
       //sample code
    }

    render() {
       return (
           <LoginComponent />
       );
    }

    function mapStateToProps(state) {
        return {
             task: state
        };
    }  

    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
        return bindActionCreators(
             Object.assign({},
                 actions),
                 dispatch);
    }

    export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login));

    Login.displayName = 'Login';
```

Sample login component

```
    //Login.Component.js

    const LoginComponent = props => {
         return (<div>hi</div>);
    }
```

My sample test suite using jest and enzyme

```
 //login.test.js
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { history, store} from '../store';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux';
describe('>>>Login --- Container', () => {       
let wrapperInner
it('should perform login container by using ComponentWapper', async () => {      
    wrapperInner = mount(<Provider store={store}>
                              <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
                                    <Login />
                              </ConnectedRouter>
                          </Provider>);       

    const instance = wrapperInner.instance();
    expect(wrapperInner.state('isShowLoader')).toBe(true);
    const responseJson = await instance.handleSubmit();       
});
});
```

[image: check this sample image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution for this issue.

```
   wrapperInner.find("Login").instance() // to access the methods

   wrapperInner.find("Login").instance().state // to access the state
```

For more details check here: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/361